# trying to load info from a vector containing classes into a two dimensional string vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector

I use an input function I made to take info from a text file and input it into the private fields of a class let's call it student, each time a record is filled with the first row from the text input file I push_back the filled class in the vector students to end up with a vector containing classes which contain the data from the input file.

So now in order to be able to perform manipulations on this data I want to load it into a two dimensional string vector but I'm having a hard time implementing this. Below is how far I have gotten, I feel like at this point I'm running in a circle. Any help is appreciated.

The parameter passed (size) is how many rows there are in the text file which is checked prior to this function running.

```
void student::loadData(int size)
{

    vector <vector<string> > tempVec(size);

    string first, middle, last, addressNum, addressStreet,
        phone, gender, email, emContactFirst, emContactLast,
        ph, emPhone, ID, age;

    //FIXME//
    for (vector<student>::iterator it = students.begin(); it != students.end(); it++){

        for (int i = 0; i < size; size++)
        {
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getName());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getId());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getAge());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getPhone());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getAddress());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getEmail());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getEmPhone());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->getEmContact());
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->gpa);
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->honors);
            tempVec[size].push_back(it->major);
            it++;
        }
    }
    //trying to output 2-dimensional array for debugging purpouses
    //(trying to mimic what the output file would look like)

        for (int i = 0; i < size; size++)
        {
            for (vector<string>::iterator z = tempVec[size].begin(); z != tempVec[size].end(); z++){
                //**FIX ME**//;
            }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.  Don't increment `size` in the for loops, you want to increment `i`.

`tempVec[size]` is outside the bounds of the vector.  You want `tempVec[i]` instead.

Don't increment `it` inside the inner for loop.